# Why has object been created without importing class?

Tags: java, class, import

I came across some java code where the following statement was present.

```
com.myproject.bar.Foo foo = new com.myproject.bar.Foo();
```

The class `com.myproject.bar.Foo` has not been imported into the class but an object of `Foo` is created in the class where this statement is written.

Why has such an implementation been done? Are there any advantages of using such an implementation over doing an import of the class `Foo`?

Comment: Is there another class with the same name in use?

Comment: I have checked the code. There is just one class with that specific name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's instantiation with the fully-qualified name of the class.

```
com.myproject.bar.Foo foo = new com.myproject.bar.Foo();
```

This doesn't require to add an `import` statement, because you've already told the compiler which is the package of the class you want to instantiate.

Sometimes this is used when there are several classes with one and the same *simple name*.

If you'd like to do this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

then you will have to import the class:

```
import com.myproject.bar.Foo;
```

Comment: You missed the __why__ part of my question. That is what I am really after.

Comment: *Sometimes this is used when there are several classes with one and the same simple name.* is a good answer to your **Why?** :)

Comment: @CodeNewbie He jsut told you.. "Sometimes this is used when there are several classes with one and the same simple name".

Answer (score 5):

An import statement *just* makes the type available by its short name without specifying the package. That's all it does. It's not like the class can't be used without an import.

Usually it's clearer to use an import instead, but sometimes that's not possible - you may want to use two classes both called `Foo` from different packages with the same class, for example. (This is most common when you've got two representations of the same entity - an API representation and a storage representation, for example.)

Without knowing what the real code looks like, we can't tell whether that was the case here, or whether an import would have been fine. If it *can* work, an import is usually more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you address the class with fully qualified name such as `com.myproject.bar.Foo`,  **you need to specify it every time** when you try to access that class.

But in case of import, you dont need to.

That's one of the **advantages**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special advantages.

But useful in case if two classes have same class name and belongs to different packages then you need to specify the fully qualified package name to differentiate both while using them in a Class.

Consider 2 classes

```
com.myproject.bar.Foo 
com.myproject.bar.innerbar.Foo
```

Now in some other class you are going to instatiate like

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Which `Foo` to import now?

To avoid that ambiguity, we need to specify the full package name.

Comment: @down voter can you please care to comment ? Any mistakes in this post. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`com.myproject.bar.Foo` is absolute class name.

`Foo` is just the Class name(relative) and it can be in any package, so to specify the package, `import` statements are used.

In cases where you have more than one class with same name, you have to use the absolute class name in your code to distinguish between the duplicate names. Example `com.Foo` and `org.Foo` then you use `Foo` for `com.Foo` and `org.Foo` for `org.Foo`.